# Why is joining on select top N from view much faster than joining on just the view?

Tags: sql-server, join, view

I have a view which has a column that is not indexed that is joined on in another query. We cannot create an index in the view because it uses outer joins.

The outer query is essentially:

```
select * from SomeTable AS T INNER JOIN
v_SomeView AS V ON T.Column = V.Column
```

The query was extremely slow and  through some experimentation we discovered that changing the query to:

```
select * from SomeTable AS T INNER JOIN
(select TOP 10000000 * from v_SomeView) AS V ON T.Column = V.Column
```

sped up the query by a significant factor (10 mins to about 5s).

The view only has about 1000 rows in it.

Can someone explain what is going on here that makes such a huge difference in performance?

Execution plans:

http://dropcanvas.com/011il

Here is the actual view **v_SecurityClassificationResult**:

```
SELECT        rc.SecurityId, rc.Status, rc.ExpiryDate, rc.StartDate, rc.ClassificationValue AS RiskClass, sg.ClassificationValue AS SecurityGroup, 
                         br.ClassificationValue AS BondRating, cur.ClassificationValue AS Currency, cod.ClassificationValue AS Country, reg.ClassificationValue AS Region
FROM            dbo.SecurityClassificationResult AS rc LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SecurityClassificationResult AS sg ON rc.SecurityId = sg.SecurityId AND rc.ExpiryDate = sg.ExpiryDate AND sg.SecurityClassificationFieldId =
                             (SELECT        SecurityClassificationFieldId
                               FROM            dbo.SecurityClassificationField
                               WHERE        (ClassificationField = 'SecurityGroup')) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SecurityClassificationResult AS br ON rc.SecurityId = br.SecurityId AND sg.ExpiryDate = br.ExpiryDate AND br.SecurityClassificationFieldId =
                             (SELECT        SecurityClassificationFieldId
                               FROM            dbo.SecurityClassificationField
                               WHERE        (ClassificationField = 'BondRating')) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SecurityClassificationResult AS cur ON rc.SecurityId = cur.SecurityId AND br.ExpiryDate = cur.ExpiryDate AND cur.SecurityClassificationFieldId =
                             (SELECT        SecurityClassificationFieldId
                               FROM            dbo.SecurityClassificationField
                               WHERE        (ClassificationField = 'Currency')) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SecurityClassificationResult AS cod ON rc.SecurityId = cod.SecurityId AND cur.ExpiryDate = cod.ExpiryDate AND cod.SecurityClassificationFieldId =
                             (SELECT        SecurityClassificationFieldId
                               FROM            dbo.SecurityClassificationField
                               WHERE        (ClassificationField = 'CountryOfDomicile')) LEFT OUTER JOIN
                         dbo.SecurityClassificationResult AS reg ON rc.SecurityId = reg.SecurityId AND cod.ExpiryDate = reg.ExpiryDate AND reg.SecurityClassificationFieldId =
                             (SELECT        SecurityClassificationFieldId
                               FROM            dbo.SecurityClassificationField
                               WHERE        (ClassificationField = 'Region'))
WHERE        (rc.SecurityClassificationFieldId =
                             (SELECT        SecurityClassificationFieldId
                               FROM            dbo.SecurityClassificationField
                               WHERE        (ClassificationField = 'RiskClass')))
```

and the other query which selects from it:

```
SELECT        count(*)
FROM            dbo.Fund_RelevantSecurity AS FRS INNER JOIN
                         dbo.SourceSystemImportLog AS SSIL ON FRS.SourceSystemImporLogtId = SSIL.SourceSystemImporLogtId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FundInstanceHolding AS FIH ON FRS.FundInstanceHoldingId = FIH.FundInstanceHoldingId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.FundInstance AS FI ON FIH.FundInstanceId = FI.FundInstanceId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.SourceSystemImportLog AS SSILOrig ON SSILOrig.SourceSystemImporLogtId = FI.SourceSystemImportLogId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Security ON FRS.SecurityId = dbo.Security.SecurityId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.Fund ON FRS.FundId = dbo.Fund.FundId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.BusinessUnitFund ON dbo.Fund.FundId = dbo.BusinessUnitFund.FundId INNER JOIN
                         dbo.BusinessUnit ON dbo.BusinessUnit.BusinessUnitId = dbo.BusinessUnitFund.BusinessUnitId RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                         (select top 2147483647 * from dbo.v_SecurityClassificationResult) AS classificationResult ON FRS.SecurityId = classificationResult.SecurityId AND GETDATE() 
                         <= classificationResult.ExpiryDate AND GETDATE() >= classificationResult.StartDate
WHERE        (SSIL.ImportStatusId <> 5)
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant execution plans?

Comment: does you view contain any function calls?

Comment: @Tanner No it does not.

Comment: How about the actual plans instead of the estimated ones? Also seeing the code for the view might help shed some light.

Comment: I created the tables and with, and without, primary keys on the join columns ( on T.Column = V.Column ) I get the same query plan. I even changed the select to 
select * from SomeTables AS T  
where  x1 in 
(select x1 from v_SomeView)  and still got the same query plan. I am running in SQL Server 2012. What SQL Server version are you running in? Is there a where condition that you are not showing us?

Comment: @SeanLange Updated with actual execution plans

Comment: I still don't know why the second query you posted would be faster but...how often do you update your statistics? The stats on Fund_RelevantSecurity appear to be pretty stale. In both plans the estimated row count is around 675k but the actual rows is more like 50k. That is a pretty significant difference. That view sure seems inefficient, it hits the same base table over and over and over.

Comment: From looking at the execution plans it looks like in the faster case the results from the view are being sorted (presumably on the column which is being joined on) before being joined with the rest of the query, but I am not sure why it doesn't do something similar in the first query.

Comment: The first query has Reason for Early Termination of Statement Optimisation = Time Out

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest for you to rebuild indexes and refresh statistics. By doing TOP N your optimizer takes another plan and seems that this one is much better. Try to check expected and actual quantities of records to find where the plan is wrong.
Another thing is that you might get better performance if you rewrite your view. You can do something like (can not check the syntax and logic as there is no structure and data provided):

```
SELECT
    rc.SecurityId ,
    rc.Status ,
    rc.ExpiryDate ,
    rc.StartDate ,
    s.ClassificationValue AS RiskClass ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN s.ClassificationValue = 'SecurityGroup' THEN s.ClassificationValue END) AS SecurityGroup ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN s.ClassificationValue = 'BondRating' THEN s.ClassificationValue END) AS BondRating ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN s.ClassificationValue = 'Currency' THEN s.ClassificationValue END) AS Currency ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN s.ClassificationValue = 'CountryOfDomicile' THEN s.ClassificationValue END) AS Country ,
    MIN(CASE WHEN s.ClassificationValue = 'Region' THEN s.ClassificationValue END) AS Region
FROM
    dbo.SecurityClassificationResult AS rc
    LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (
    SELECT s.ClassificationValue,
            sf.ClassificationField
    FROM  dbo.SecurityClassificationResult AS s
    JOIN dbo.SecurityClassificationField AS sf
      ON sf.SecurityClassificationFieldId = s.SecurityClassificationFieldId
    WHERE sf.ClassificationField IN ( 'SecurityGroup', 'BondRating', 'Currency', 'CountryOfDomicile' 'Region')

    ) s
    ON s.SecurityId = rc.SecurityId
WHERE
    ( rc.SecurityClassificationFieldId = (
                                           SELECT
                                            SecurityClassificationFieldId
                                           FROM
                                            dbo.SecurityClassificationField
                                           WHERE
                                            ( ClassificationField = 'RiskClass' )
                                         ) )
GROUP BY     rc.SecurityId ,
    rc.Status ,
    rc.ExpiryDate ,
    rc.StartDate ,
    s.ClassificationValue
```